# Debian webbased server management

Tags: debian

I'm running a debian lenny server at home which functions basically as a NAS, it's also running some other basic stuff like LAMP stack. So heres the thing, I'm moving out and my server is staying home so I wont be around for updates and help when accounts go lost or samba shares don't function.

I've read this article in a magazine about a webinterface called e-box (its called zentyal as of sep. 2010) for server management, i was wondering if anyone knows if I could get zentyal to run on Debian (zentyal is made for ubuntu) or do you know any alternative solution?

Comment: Ok i found the solution on the would it work part, http://forum.zentyal.org/index.php?topic=3105.0 Wont work on debian lenny. So my other question remains, does anyone know a nice webinterface for debian lenny?

Comment: Zentyal wasn't working for me ended up running a new debian squeeze install with webmin for management

Answer (score 1):

I haven't thoroughly tested it, but I liked [SysCP](http://www.syscp.org)

Comment: This looks promising although i'm looking for some samba management aswell, i gess i could add it seporately